cannot enter the url manually after writing a middleware in nextjs14 (app router)
since i've added the middleware which i will provide to you,
i cannot enter the urls manually and it errors out.
i'm using "next-intl" internationalization and i created a middleware to handle language change routes for the "baseUrl".
i don't know what to do!
i tried different kind of middleware handling but all of them seemed to not be working properly either.
any suggestions ?
here's the middleware :
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';

export default createMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales: ['en', 'fa'],

  // Used when no locale matches
  defaultLocale: 'en'
});

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(fa|en)/:path*' , '/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)' , '/([\\w-]+)?/api/(.+)']
};

and here's the next.config.mjs :
import createNextIntlPlugin from "next-intl/plugin";

const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["utfs.io"],
  },
};

export default withNextIntl(nextConfig);
